# glusterfs Unable to read gsyncd status file

Tags: ssh, replication, glusterfs, geo-replication

I wanted to try glusterfs geo-replication in some virtualboxes on my computer for later use distributed on multiple sites.

I installed glusterfs 3.6 on ubuntu 32bit servers like this:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.6
apt-get update -qq
apt-get install glusterfs-server -y
```

In `/etc/hosts` on every virtualbox is an entry like this so that i can use hostnames:

```
192.168.1.1 ivymaster.com
192.168.1.2 ivyslave2.com
192.168.1.3 ivyslave1.com
```

First I created and startet a volume on master (`force` to create on rootfs):

```
gluster volume create master ivymaster.com:/var/glustermaster/ force
gluster volume start master
```

Works fine. I setup passwordless root login with `ssh-copy-id` and logged in one time manually to check if this is setup correct and the host is stored in `known_hosts`.

I was not able to setup synchronisation into a directory like described in [Geo-Replication Terminology - Understanding the URI](https://github.com/Kaushikbv/Geo-replication-Documentaion/blob/master/doc.md). Creation of geo-replication failed with URI problem.

```
gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com:/var/slave2 start
 Staging failed on localhost. Please check the log file for more details.
```

Logfile contains entries like `Invalid slave name`, `Unable to store slave volume name`, `Unable to fetch slave or confpath details`.

When I create a volume on `ivyslave2.com` and create geo-replication with usage of this volume, this works:

```
 gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com::slave2 create push-pem force
  Creating geo-replication session between master & ivyslave2.com::slave2 has been successful
```

Unfortunately, `gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com::slave2 status` sais that the status of the replication is faulty.

```
MASTER NODE      MASTER VOL    MASTER BRICK                SLAVE                    STATUS    CHECKPOINT STATUS    CRAWL STATUS        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ivyVirtMaster    master       /var/glusterfs_master_nv        ivyslave2.com::slave2    faulty    N/A                  N/A
```

After executing this command, logfile on master contains `Using passed config template(/var/lib/glusterd/geo-replication/master_ivyslave2.com_slave2/gsyncd.conf).`, `Unable to read gsyncd status file`, `Unable to read the statusfile for /var/glusterfs_master_nv brick for  master(master), ivyslave2.com::slave2(slave) session`.

Logfile on slave contains `Received status volume req for volume slave2`, `tune2fs exited with non-zero exit status`, `failed to get inode size`.

Is this the volume on slave faulty? How can a geo replication be setup without a volume? Is there something wrong in geo replication configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As of gluster 3.5 you cannot use a folder as a geo-replication destination.  As of 3.5 you must replicate from one gluster volume to another gluster volume.

As to the problem you experienced with the gluster volume to gluster volume geo-replication there are some other commands you may or may not have issued.

Prior to the 'create' you need to

- make sure password-less ssh exists between the master and the slaves
- you must generate the keys gluster uses for communication between the masters and the slaves by running this command on one of the masters:

`gluster system:: execute gsec_create`

Next you would run the create as you did, but without the force option.  If your create failed without force something is wrong and using force will just mask over the issue and produce a broken setup.

After you do the 'create push-pem' successfully (without force) you need to start the replication process:

`gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com::slave2 start`